# Setting up SBO Transaction Notification

Tags: sql

I need to set up an SBO Transaction Notification in SAP B1 9.

This should look at NULL fields and display to the user the actual field that has null values. The query itself should be looking at several fields, but only display an indicator of the fields that are supposed to be filled up.

Answer (score 0):

This query is for invoices, verify that the sales person is not null on invoice:

```
If @object_type ='13' 

BEGIN
    SELECT @V=-1

    SELECT @v=ISNULL(slpcode,-1)
    FROM OINV
    WHERE DocEntry = Cast(@list_of_Cols_Val_Tab_Del as int)


    If @v IS NULL or @v=NULL or @v='' or @v=-1
    Begin
        set @Error = 1
        set @Error_Message = 'ERROR - please select a sales person. ' + cast(@v as nvarchar(10))

    End

END
```